# extracting text between "[-" and "-]" using grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have a text file where certain words/phrases are tagged

```
[-sample text-]
```

or

```
{+sample text+}
```

How can I use grep to extract those bracketed words in the text?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Grep with PCRE Support

You're describing what appears to be word-diff format. This is difficult to do with standard grep, but is easy to do with more powerful regular expression engines like PCRE.

With the PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression) library compiled into your grep, or the pcregrep binary, you can use certain types of zero-width assertions in your pattern. For example, assuming that you have the following file contents:

```
foo [-sample text 1-] bar {+sample text 2+} baz
```

you can get the correct result with:

```
$ pcregrep -o '(?<={\+|\[-).*?(?=\+}|-\])' /tmp/foo
sample text 1
sample text 2
```

Comment: This matches also `[- sample text +}`; much less elegant, but in my humble opinion more precise would be `grep -Po '(?<=\{\+).*?(?=\+\})|(?<=\[-).*?(?=-\])'`

Comment: ideally, I would like to place all removals into the first column of a spreadsheet file, and all additions in the second column. Any ideas? So, 1) when [-sample text 1-] is NOT followed by {+sample text 2+}

column 1: sample text 1 
column 2: 


2) when [-sample text 1-] is followed by {+sample text 2+}

column 1: sample text 1 
column 2: sample text 2


3) when {+sample text 2+} is NOT preceded by [-sample text 1-] 

column 1: 
column 2: sample text 2

Comment: @radishman You're now asking questions entirely outside the scope of your original question. In addition, SO is not a code-writing service. Please make an attempt to write your own code, and then post a new question to address specific, narrow problems you may be having. Good luck!

Comment: @codegnome - many thanks for your help! Obviously I'm new to all of this. Will endeavor to learn and teach myself more. Thanks again